# How to change the target folder for afFancordion results?

Tags: fantom, fancordion

When I run afConcordion fixtures within my Fantom project, the generated fixtures end up in this folder:

```
$FAN_HOME/temp/concordion/no-name
```

But I'd like them to be written in a folder called `target` under my project's folder.

Looking at [afConcordion documentation](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afConcordion/) it seems that is possible, at least for afBedSheet applications, if I extend the ConcordionRunner, e.g.

```
class MyConcordionRunner : ConcordionRunner {

    new make(|This|? f := null) : super(f) {
        outputDir = `concordion-results/`.toFile
        // other runner configuration...
    }
}
```

But I'd like to use the default ConcordionRunner instead of implementing my own and still decide where I want my test results. Is it possible, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is! `ConcordionRunner` is a standard class and `outputDir` is just a field, so...

```
runner := ConcordionRunner()
runner.outputDir = `target/`.toFile
```

Or, using the it-block ctor parameter:

```
runner := ConcordionRunner() { it.outputDir = `target/`.toFile }
```

Putting it together with `FixtureTest`:

```
class TestStuff : FixtureTest {

    ...

    override ConcordionRunner concordionRunner() {
        ConcordionRunner() { it.outputDir = `target/`.toFile }
    }
}
```